# How to do Transaction begin and commit in different methods of different classes?

Tags: php, laravel, transactions, laravel-5.4

For e.g.

A.php

```
class A{
  public function abc(){
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $result = Model::save();
  }
}
```

B.php

```
class B{
  public function cde(){
    DB::commit(); //or DB::rollback;
  }
}
```

These are two classes from different files.

Steps :

1. $a->abc() first will get called
2. then payment operation
3. then $b->cde() will get called
4. if payment success then commit
5. else rollback

Can we achieve this?

I had tried, but no luck. Does anyone have any alternative to cope with this problem?

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

1. I am registering the user and saving its files.
2. Then I begin transaction and save files, so as of now no data is saved in the database. It's in transaction which is yet to be done.
3. Now page is redirected to payment URL so I lost all files data and form data too
4. When payment will redirect to return URL on the basis of payment response (success or failure), I want to save or remove i.e. commit or rollback the data.

On the basis of this, I thought that way.

Can you please suggest any alternative to this problem as this my thinking not working?

Comment: Generally wouldn't recommend it, as it's non-intuitive and difficult to follow.... do the start transaction and commit/rollback in whatever calls these methods in these classes

Comment: You are deleting some model (record) in B class regarding payment gateway response. Why you are using A class at all? Just do what you need in B class. Wouldn't that be logic?

Comment: @MarkBaker can you please go through edit portion of my question? I know I am wrong, but need some hint or idea to achieve solve this hurdle?

Comment: @Tpojka : I wrote clearly my requirement in EDIT portion, please go through it

Comment: I mean handle the start transaction/rollback/commit in your controller class, not in your models or services

Comment: @MarkBaker Currently its in repository. which have its server side validation with `$this->validator($request);` this. So is there any other way to achieve this? I don't mind to change the flow but I hope I am clear with my concern.